# Failed to complete step 16 in Oracle grid installation

Tags: oracle, unix, oracle11g, database-administration, superuser

The error message is mentioned below:-

```
INS-32128] Installer has failed to login as 'root' user with the specified password. Specify a valid 'root' user password.

Additional Information:
Summary of the failed nodes rac02  - PRCZ-2006 : Unable to establish SSH connection to node "rac02" to execute command "/usr/bin/id"
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 391  - Cause: Cause Of Problem Not Available  - Action: User Action Not Available
```

I am trying to setup a two node RAC

Although from the outside of the installer able to connect the node via root through pass wordless ssh

Answer (score 0):

hard to help you on this. There are a lot of logfiles which can provide useful information what exactly goes wrong. Do you run cluvfy suscessfull before setup? 
Take a look in the docs for your oracle version. there are a points "continue failed installation" that can help.
You have to provide more information about what you have done from the beginning
or raise a sr to get help by oracle.

Lookm here for your error. Sure you type the correct passwort?
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ERRMG/INS-30001.htm#ERRMG-GUID-B78A0245-9343-44D4-A4F7-59C04831C9D8

At which point in this tutorial you are getting this error?

Comment: Yah, I types my password correctly. Password less ssh connection is correctly set up between rac01 oracle and rac02 oracle but not happening the password less connection between root and oracle of node 1 from oracle to root . Is it the reason

Comment: you only need the Key-Based Authentication for the user which hole and install the grid software. So in most cases this is the user oracle. For root this is not necessary.

Comment: But the error message is saying log in as root user and also the instruction I am following says ssh authentication from both the user required

Comment: [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwislt_Vj-raAhWMMI8KHQZeAMcQFggrMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.evensh.com%2F12cRAConVirtualBox.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3oLhqij46buM38EqWdzFpg) I am following this document exactly step by step